# How can I roll the database back to the backup

Tags: 8, backups

I have a problem with a module the site functions but  I need to roll the database back to the backup I took before deploying the module. How can I do that?I am using D8

Comment: How did you take the backup?

Comment: At cpanel-Back up-Download a MySQL Database Backup. I saved it locally on my computer.

Comment: Cpanel generally links to PHPMyAdmin - if you go to that and select your database, there should be an 'import' tab. Go there and upload your backup.

Comment: I also have a folder on my computer with a zipped file containing all the site files i backed up Should I also delete the site files I have now in the root directory and upload the backuped ones, or just proceed with the database?

Comment: You want the code on the server to match the code as it was when you took the backup. So if any files have been changed or removed since you took the backup, you need to make sure those files are the same state they were in when you took the backup. However, if you only added files after taking the backup (not changing or removing any files), then you shouldn't need to replace the files on the server.

Comment: Thank you so much, all is clear now. You explain very well. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Drush](http://www.drush.org).

All you need to do is to run, inside a Drupal instalation, the following command:

`drush sqlc < path/to/backup.sql`

*You may want to drop your current database before that. The command is:

`drush sql-drop -y`